# Use jQuery one() function on multiple table cells

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem with jquery. I have table in which i have multiple rows. When i click one of the rows (only once) i should send a post with jquery. The problem is i cant use the one() function for this, because the event happens for all the table cells.
Here is the code:

```
        $("#tabel_notificari").one("click", ".rand_notif td:last-child" ,function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var idNotif=$(this).parent().attr("record");
        $.post("../template/masa/gestionare_notificare.php",{id:idNotif, status:3}, function(data){
        $(this).parent().prev(".spacer_2").remove();
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);return true;});
    });
```

Is anyone able to helpme with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable outside the click event, and use `on` instead of `one`...

```
var clicked = false;
$("#tabel_notificari").on("click", ".rand_notif td:last-child" ,function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!clicked) {
        clicked = true;
        var idNotif = $(this).parent().attr("record");
        $.post("../template/masa/gestionare_notificare.php",{id:idNotif, status:3}, function(data){
            $(this).parent().prev(".spacer_2").remove();
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

That will only allow the click code to run once, regardless of which cell is clicked.

Comment: i tried that, but is there any otehr way to just use the one() function?

Comment: No there isn't.  It will attach itself to all elements that match your selector and run once for each of them.

Comment: It would be great if it'd be that way , but my problem is exactly the opposite: It will attach itself to all elements that match my selector and run once for all of them.

Comment: you said it will run for each on of them(what im trying to accomplish), but it actually runs onece for all(if i have 3 table rows and i click one of them, it will only work for the clicked one and not for the others :( )